# Objective-c enum getting error "... is not convertible to 'NativeObject'" in Swift

Tags: ios, enums, swift

I have a typedef defined in my objective-c files:

```
typedef enum : long{
    tb_closed_k = 0,
    tb_open_k
 } MyState;
```

Now I create a member of this type in my Swift class:

```
@objc class myClass {
    var activeState: MyState = tb_closed_k

   func testState( state:MyState ){
       if state != activeState{
         ..do something
       }
    }
}
```

so the line comparing the states gives me the error "MyState is not convertible to 'NativeObject'. I am using xCode 6-Beta3. Any Ideas.

thanks
Reza

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your enum is not directly importable into Swift because it does not use the `NS_ENUM` macro. Either rewrite the enum in Swift (using `Int`, not `long`) or incorporate `NS_ENUM`. In any case, using `long` here is a really bad idea in any case, because it won't come into Swift as a native type, whereas NSInteger will come in as Int.

Comment: just need to remember to use MyState.tb_closed_k when using the enum